# CSS how to fix an element to scroll horizontally with the page but not vertically?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created an example to help explain. http://jsfiddle.net/9AUbj/1/

```
<style>
div#one {}
div#two {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 1000px;
}
div#three {
    height: 1000px;
}
</style>
...
<div id="one">Hello World!</div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
```

I would like "Hello World!" to move horizontally with the window when the user scrolls horizontally. But I **DON'T** want it to move vertically with the window when the user scrolls vertically. What is the best way to do this? I'm using Bootstrap and jQuery UI, in case those might help. However, I am also interested in a pure CSS solution.

Thanks in advance :-)
ktm

Comment: why does your page scroll horizontally?

Comment: There is no CSS way that I know of :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you scroll the window, reposition the #one element to always be on screen. Also, #one should be position: absolute.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $("#one").css({
        left: $(this).scrollLeft()
    });
});
```

Here's your fiddle with the new code: http://jsfiddle.net/9AUbj/15/

Comment: Yah, something weird changed, let me post it again.

Answer (score 2):

While I admit that a CSS-only solution would be cool, you can't apply positioning based on axis.  With how fixed positioning works, you can't force a horizontal scroll on the *document* even if the fixed-position element extends outside.

However, this is *very* simple to do with jQuery

```
$(document).on('scroll', function () {
    $("#two").css('top', $(this).scrollTop());
});
```

This requires `#two` to be absolutely positioned.

http://jsfiddle.net/9AUbj/16/

Comment: Originally I thought there was no CSS solution, but we had this element in our page which threw me off: http://jsfiddle.net/EP4dK/. This element does exactly what I have described, without any of our own JavaScript applied to it. I wonder if jQuery UI runs JavaScript on this element? (i.e., to make it scroll horizontally with the page but not vertically).

Comment: @ktm5124 it seems we have a different understanding of what the term "scroll"  means

Comment: Based on my comment? That was only meant to show the HTML for the element that threw me off - not demonstrate the scrolling. Basically, I have a table with 20+ columns in it, and I would like a menu overhead to be always present when you scroll horizontally with the table. But I don't want the menu to be omnipresent when you scroll vertically with the table.

Comment: @ktm5124 oh, I misunderstood; I thought you wanted the opposite scroll direction preserved.  You can just change `top` to `left` in the code above, but I guess @MattDiamant already did that

Answer (score 0):

i used this code

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $("#one").css({
        left: $(this).scrollLeft()
    });
});
```

and it works perfect on Chrome , but on internet explorer when i drag the horizontal scroll, the fixed content starts to flicker :(