# fixed div is not scrolling with form on narrowing the window size

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed div on the top of the page but the content of the div is not scrolling with the html body on narrowing the window size. Can anybody help me out?

here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/ALqd6/

css:

.header-container

{

```
width:100%;

position:fixed !important;

display:block;

overflow:hidden;

top:0;

background:#000;

height:70px;

color:red;
```

}

html:

```
    <div class="header-container" style="min-width:1200px;margin:0 auto;">
        <table cellpadding=19 class="hc-table" style="height:70px;">
            <tr>
                <td>m-1</td>
                <td>m-2</td>
                <td>m-3</td>
                <td>m-4</td>
                <td>m-5</td>
                <td>m-6</td>
                <td>m-7</td>
                <td>m-8</td>
                <td>m-9</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>  
       </div></div>
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO ... You may need to improve your question please add relevant code to reproduce the problem. We can't know what is the problem without seen your html and css code.

Comment: what @Danko said, if possible please also post a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `position` attribute [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), when you use `position: fixed`, you *"position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and **doesn't move** when scrolled"*.

This means that the object will stay in the current position regardless of how you scroll the page vertically or horizontally.

To achieve the result you mentioned, I believe you would need to use a JavaScript method that changes the div's `left` attribute to reflect the horizontal scroll performed by the user in the case when the window's width is not big enough to fit the whole content.

Some links that could be useful for you regarding this JavaScript approach are:

- [Horizontal page scrolling using Javascript](http://paulicio.us/items/view/24/horizontal-page-scrolling-using-javascript)
- [Position a Div "Fixed" Vertically and "Absolute" Horizontally within a "Position:Relative" Container Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327093/position-a-div-fixed-vertically-and-absolute-horizontally-within-a-position)
- [CSS how to fix an element to scroll horizontally with the page but not vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101989/css-how-to-fix-an-element-to-scroll-horizontally-with-the-page-but-not-verticall)
- [How to animate a div move horizontally when page is scroll down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20166546/how-to-animate-a-div-move-horizontally-when-page-is-scroll-down)

Comment: Thank for the reply but If I use the answer from jsfiddle link using javascript then the div is blinking on scrolling down the document.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly this is what you want. 
http://jsfiddle.net/vn5Uj/

```
.header-container{
 width:100%;
 !important;
display:block;
overflow:hidden;
top:0;
background:#000;
height:70px;
color:red;
}
```

Comment: Nope. This way the top div would scroll out of the page if an user scrolls the page vertically.

Comment: in your solution div is not fixed on top of the document. please read the question carefully